# sed with filename from pipe

Tags: sed, pipe, ls

In a folder I have many files with several parameters in filenames, e.g (just with one parameter) `file_a1.0.txt`, `file_a1.2.txt` etc.
These are generated by a c++ code and I'd need to take the last one (in time) generated. I don't know a priori what will be the value of this parameter when the code is terminated. After that I need to copy the 2nd line of this last file.

To copy the 2nd line of the any file, I know that this `sed` command works:

```
sed -n 2p filename
```

I know also how to find the last generated file:

```
ls -rtl file_a*.txt | tail -1
```

#### Question:

how to combine these two operation? Certainly it is possible to pipe the 2nd operation to that sed operation but I dont know how to include filename from pipe as input to that sed command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this,

```
ls -rt1 file_a*.txt | tail -1 | xargs sed -n '2p'
```

**(OR)**

```
sed -n '2p' `ls -rt1 file_a*.txt | tail -1`

sed -n '2p' $(ls -rt1 file_a*.txt | tail -1)
```

Comment: it doesnt work. gives a long error message started with sed: invalid option -- 'w'

Comment: I use Ubuntu Linux. No, file names do not have any space.

Comment: @Reza, It should work. I tested in Ubuntu. It is working perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesnt work for me. This is exactly copy-paste from my terminal: ls -rtl param*pump10.2* | tail -1 | xargs sed -n '2p'
sed: invalid option -- 'w'
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

  -n, --quiet, --silent
                 suppress automatic printing of pattern space
  -e script, --expression=script
                 add the script to the commands to be executed

Comment: Use option `-rt` not `-rtl`

Comment: @Reza, `-l` will give you the long list output. That's why, I used `ls -1 (one)`

Comment: Exactly! I just found that and it works even with your first suggestion and now works perfect!! Thanks a lot for your prompt help.

Comment: when i try to pip to sed via xargs, I get "illegal byte sequence"!

Answer (score 4):

Typically you can put a command in back ticks to put its output at a particular point in another command - so

```
sed -n 2p `ls -rt name*.txt | tail -1 `
```

Alternatively - and preferred, because it is easier to nest etc -

```
sed -n 2p $(ls -rt name*.txt | tail -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

-r in `ls` is reverse order.

```
   -r, --reverse
          reverse order while sorting
```

But it is not good idea when used it with `tail -1`.

With below change (head -1 without r option in ls), performance will be better, that you needn't wait to list all files then pipe to tail command

```
sed -n 2p $(ls -t1 name*.txt | head -1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution: taking the file names from a pipe of grep results to feed to sed. I've copied my answer here for the search & replace, but perhaps this example can help as it calls sed for each of the names found in the pipe:

this command to simply find all the files:

```
grep -i -l -r foo ./*
```

this one to exclude this_shell.sh (in case you put the command in a script called *this_shell.sh*), tee the output to the console to see what happened, and then use sed on each file name found to replace the text foo with bar:

```
grep -i -l -r --exclude "this_shell.sh" foo ./* | tee  /dev/fd/2 | while read -r x; do sed -b -i 's/foo/bar/gi' "$x"; done
```

I chose this method, as I didn't like having all the timestamps changed for files not modified. Feeding the grep result allows only the files with target text to be looked at (thus likely may improve performance / speed as well)

be sure to backup your files & test before using. May not work in some environments for files with embedded spaces. (?)

fwiw - I had some problems using the tail method, it seems that the entire dataset was generated before calling tail on just the last item.